# How do I use the current date in an HQL query with an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to write this query using Hibernate 3 and Oracle 10.

```
from Alert alert
where alert.expiration > current_date()
order by alert.priority, alert.updated, alert.name
```

It's creating SQL like this -

```
Hibernate: select alert0_.ANNOUNCEMENTS_ID as ANNOUNCE1_1_, alert0_.ANNOUNCEMENT
S_NAME as ANNOUNCE2_1_, alert0_.ANNOUNCEMENTS_PRIORITY as ANNOUNCE3_1_, alert0_.
ANNOUNCEMENTS_EXPIRATION as ANNOUNCE4_1_, alert0_.ANNOUNCEMENTS_UPDATE_DATE as A
NNOUNCE5_1_ from NYC311_ANNOUNCEMENTS alert0_ where (alert0_.ANNOUNCEMENTS_EXPIR
ATION>current_date()) order by  alert0_.ANNOUNCEMENTS_PRIORITY , alert0_.ANNOUNC
EMENTS_UPDATE_DATE , alert0_.ANNOUNCEMENTS_NAME
```

I'm getting all of these wacky errors like "missing right parenthesis" when there is apparently perfectly balanced parenthesis.

Why is Oracle freaking out at this? Is there a better way to write my HQL query?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `current_date`?

Hibernate will translate it to the proper dialect.

I did not find a real "Hibernate will translate this to that" reference documentation, but the expression, in general, can be found in  [HQL Expressions for Hibernate 4.3](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-expressions).

Then there is the [Java Persistence API 2.0 (JPA)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317) specification which defines expressions for the Java Persistence query language (JPQL) and their meaning e.g. for `current_date`:

> 4.6.17.2.3 Datetime Functions functions_returning_datetime:= CURRENT_DATE | CURRENT_TIME | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP The datetime functions
>   return the value of current date, time, and timestamp on the database
>   server.

Answer (score 9):

Is `current_date()` a Hibernate function?

I would use `sysdate` instead. like this:

```
where alert.expiration > sysdate
```

Or to ignore time of day:

```
where alert.expiration > trunc(sysdate)
```

Comment: Current_date and Current_timestamp are Oracle functions. Current_date = Sysdate but Oracle doesn't need () after a function call.

Comment: CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() are also Hibernate HQL Functions. ("Java Persistence With Hibernate")

Comment: just pass CURRENT_DATE() in your query like for example: "and date=CURRENT_DATE()";