# Hibernate current date not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I have re-written this question to make it clear.

I have an entity like this:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
        name = "myObj.findCurrentUsingFunction", 
        query = "from MyObj where insertDate = current_date() "),

    @NamedQuery(
        name = "myObj.findCurrentUsingParameter", 
        query = "from MyObj where insertDate = :currentDate")
})

public class MyObj {
    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date insertDate;

    /* getter, setter */
}
```

I have a failing test:

```
@Test
public void findCurrentUsingFunction() throws Exception {
    final MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
    myObj.setInsertDate(new Date());
    final Session session = dao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(myObj);
    final Query namedQuery = 
        session.getNamedQuery("myObj.findCurrentUsingFunction");
    final List results = namedQuery.list();
    Assert.assertEquals("size",1L, (long) results.size());
}
```

> Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual Hibernate:
>   insert into MyObj (insertDate, id) values (?, ?) Hibernate: select
>   myobj0_.id as id0_, myobj0_.insertDate as insertDate0_ from MyObj
>   myobj0_ where myobj0_.insertDate=current_date
>
> java.lang.AssertionError: size expected:<1> but was:<0>

and a passing test

```
@Test
public void findCurrentUsingParameter() throws Exception {
    final MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
    myObj.setInsertDate(new Date());
    final Session currentSession = dao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(myObj);
    final Query namedQuery =
        currentSession.getNamedQuery("myObj.findCurrentUsingParameter");
    namedQuery.setDate("currentDate", new Date());
    final List results = namedQuery.list();
    Assert.assertEquals("size",1L, (long) results.size());
}
```

the dialect is:

> hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

Comment: Your hyperlink is broken. What doesn't work? Exception, stack trace? Not the result you're expecting? What's the mapping of insertDate? What's its column type in database? What's its value in database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use the current date in an HQL query with an Oracle database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513317/how-do-i-use-the-current-date-in-an-hql-query-with-an-oracle-database) (take a look at [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513317/how-do-i-use-the-current-date-in-an-hql-query-with-an-oracle-database/513367#513367))

Comment: I will re-write the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 5):

You are using a sql function inside an HSQL statement, so it doesn't work. Either remove the brackets to use the hibernate current_date function, like this:

```
@NamedQuery(
    name = "entity.findCurrent", 
    query = "from EntityName where insertDate = current_date")
```

Or, I would do it like this (in fact I would also use [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to create my datetime variable currentDate)

```
@NamedQuery(
    name = "entity.findCurrent", 
    query = "from EntityName where insertDate = :currentDate")
```

Then pass in date when you call the named query

```
session.getNamedQuery(findCurrent).setDate("currentDate", currentDate);
```

or you could use a [critiera](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html).

Comment: Well, of course I could do that, and it is what I am doing until I get a solution to this. But the question is about why the current_date() function doesn't work for me.

Comment: @NimChimpsky: current_date() is also a HQL function. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-expressions

Comment: @JB Nizet, without the brackets it is, with the brackets it isn't.

Comment: Then there's a bug in the Hibernate reference documentation.

Comment: @JB Nizet more details now provided in the re-written question. I tried with and without the brackets.

Comment: @JB Nizet the link you posted shows the correct syntax in their example queries - which is the same as my answer